# Empty Cell Causing Type Error, Clearing Cell Fixes

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that's to check if Cell L contains a specific string, and if not, to check whether H < I. This is executed on a pre-built spreadsheet exported from the web.

```
If InStr(Cells(count, "L"), "Apples") > 0 Then
    'stuff
ElseIf CDbl(Cells(count, "H")) < CDbl(Cells(count, "I")) Then
    'stuff
Else
    'stuff
End If
```

The issue I'm running into is that if `Apples` is not found and cell I# is empty, a `Type Mismatch` occurs on `CDbl(Cells(count, "I"))`. However, I've found if I go in and clear the contents of this cell, everything runs okay. But I have no clue as to why this fixes the issue, as clearing it doesn't actually appear to change the cell or its contents in any way, so far as I can tell.

I've verified that the cell is completely empty (no spaces, nothing) prior to clearing, as well as formatted identically as to after I clear it (text). For now, I've added the following to clear any cells before the above checks are run, and that prevents errors from occurring.

```
If Cells(count, "I") = "" Then
    Cells(count, "I").Clear
End If
```

Comment: Null and empty are different.  You could check if LEN(cell)<>0
See: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/468838-null-value-vs-empty-cell-vs-vs-0-vs-blank-cell.html

Comment: @Jan Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `CDbl()` misbehaves, consider using your own UDF, something like:

```
Public Function cdblx(v As Variant) As Double
    If IsNumeric(v) Then
        cdblx = CDbl(v)
    Else
        cdblx = 0
    End If
End Function
```